# What is the Hibernate equivalent of JDO makeTransient

Tags: java, hibernate

I am porting my Dao layer from KodoJDO to Hibernate.
I am keeping my menus in the database and based on a user's entitlements I prune a local copy to display only what the user is allowed to do.

When I did this in KodoJDO I had to make the objest I was pruning transient because I didn't want to write the changes back to the db.

I don't see any equivalent function in Hibernate. Is there one? How do I keep these changes from getting written back to the db.

Here is the prune function.

```
 public void prune(Collection<Entitlement> ents)
 {
  Session session=PersistenceManager.getManager();
  // Rewrite----------------------------------
  //session.makeTransient(this);

  for (Iterator<Leaf> iter = leafs.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
  {
   Leaf l = (Leaf) iter.next();
   if(!l.isAllowed(ents))
   {
    iter.remove();
   }
  }
  for (Iterator<Branch> iter = branches.iterator(); iter.hasNext();)
  {
   Branch b = (Branch) iter.next();
   if(b!= this)
   {
    b.prune(ents);
   }
   if (b.hasNoChildren())
   {
    iter.remove();
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment on answers. I accepted the one that was most complete, but the answers by skaffman and Affe were valuable as well.

Comment: Thanks for the code indent skaffman. You hit submit while I was only half way doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JPA 2.0 it's `entityManager.detach(..)`. I'm explicitly giving the JPA version, because it is advisable to use hibernate through JPA.

If we look how is the `detach(..)` method implemented in hibernate's `EntityManagerImpl`, it uses the `getSession().evict(entity)` on the underlying session

But note that you should rarely need to do this. I don't know whether it's a common practice in JDO, but in JPA/Hibernate it is not needed if you are using them properly.

As per your comment - if you want to use the hibernate entities as objects whose values you change but do not persist. I haven't used them like that, because I usually don't have an open session / entity manager in my view. Or I use value objects. If you both have an open session in the view, and you don't have value objects - yes, this is a valid usage.

Comment: What do you mean by "using them properly"? In the code above I am starting with live, persistent objects, then I make modifications that I do not want persisted. I am using the persistent version as a template. Is that using them properly?

Comment: @Aaron - well, I've never used them like that, but see my upcoming update.

Answer (score 2):

`evict(Object object)` is the method on the `Session` interface that you're looking for.

Also note that the vocabulary is a bit different in hibernate.  As per the Session javadoc:

```
transient: never persistent, not associated with any Session
persistent: associated with a unique Session
detached: previously persistent, not associated with any Session
```

So transient doesn't mean quite the same thing.  'Detached' is the word they use for what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

`Session.evict(entity)` probably [has the semantics](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#evict%28java.lang.Object%29) you're looking for:

> Remove this instance from the session cache. Changes to the instance will not be synchronized with the database.